# Work with environment variables in Python

Tags: python, environment-variables, environment

How can I set my DATABASE_URL as an environment variable in Python on Windows?

Comment: Do you have an example or a specific issue? You will be more likely to receive an answer if you post some code. Environment variables are available in the `os` module in `os.environ`

Answer (score 0):

With the `os` module of the standard library;

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ.get('NON_EXISTANT')
None
>>> os.environ.get('HOME')
/home/username
```

If you want to set such a variable;

```
>>> os.environ['YOUR_VARIABLE'] = 'your_value'
```

***Note:*** print all available environment variables with `os.environ`.